# Error al abrir conexion mssql_connect() Php

Tags: sql

Tengo un problema con una aplicacion, se realizan dos conexiones a dos diferentes base de datos de SQL,
la primer conexion funciona correctamente, pero a la segunda base de datos es imposible conectarse, al momento de intentar conocer el error no me regresa ningun mensaje, tengo el siguiente codigo

```
try {
     $this->cn = mssql_connect($host_sisropa,$user_sisropa,$pass_sisropa) or die( 
     mssql_get_last_message() . '-Error de SQLc');
    }
catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e;
    }
```

he intentado sin el try catch y la funcion mssql_get_last_message regresa un string vacio, cuando coloco los parametros que recibe mssql_connect un valor incorrecto de login o base de datos si me regresa un error, pero al momento de poner todas las variables correctamente, no se realiza la conexion y mssql_get_last_message() regresa un string vacio.
Alguna idea de que pueda estar ocurriendo? o como poder conocer el error realmente

Comment: Si ya estás usando un try/catch entonces esto: `or die( mssql_get_last_message()` no debería ser lo que apliques

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu versión de PHP? `mssql_connect` fue removida de PHP a partir de la v. 7, por tanto si estás en PHP 7 o superior [debes buscar otras alternativas como indica el Manual de PHP](https://php.uz/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php).